# How do I resolve "Serverless Function has exceeded the unzipped maximum size of 250 MB" error on Vercel?

Tags: python, django, vercel

I have a personal project that I am building in Python using Django. When deploying it to Vercel, it worked fine until eventually the amount of libraries that I imported (included in my **requirements.txt** file) became too large, I assume, and now I face the "Serverless Function has exceeded the unzipped maximum size of 250 MB" error.

The library that takes up the most space is **Wordcloud** (and **botocore / boto3**).

Surely there must be a way around this? As far as I'm aware, paying for a higher tier of Vercel will not resolve this issue. Is there any workaround to this issue, or is the best option to just use a different service other than Vercel?

This is my requirements.txt:

```
Django==4.2.8
psycopg2-binary==2.9.8
Pillow==8.2.0
django-storages==1.14.2
boto3==1.34.4
botocore==1.34.4
Pyrebase4==4.7.1

regex==2020.11.13
python-dateutil==2.8.2
textblob==0.17.1
nltk==3.6.3
json5==0.9.14
jsonpath-ng==1.5.3
jsonpointer==2.4
jsonschema==4.19.0
jsonschema-specifications==2023.7.1
wordcloud==1.9.2
matplotlib==3.7.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
```

Obviously when I remove the libraries from my project that takes up the most space, it does build successfully.

So the problem is not with my code itself, and it does build and start up successfully when I open
a local instance.

I'm still relatively new with Python, so I would appreciate any help, even if it is "basic" - I'd take all the pointers I can get!